# Win 8: Folder copies to network drive, but the files in it don't copy

Tags: networking, windows-8, external-hard-drive

I can transfer files between my network drive and my Win 8 computer, but if I drag a folder from my computer to the drive, the folder is empty on the Network drive. My XP computer can do this operation, so drive has the capability. I can drag a folder with files from the network drive to my computer, just can't do it in the opposite direction.

Why isn't this common file operation working?

Comment: Are the files protected? Perhaps you need to make sure the permissions are allowed for write to the files. Also is the network drive local or over the internet to another network?